# Android Geolocation not working on 3G mode, but working on Wifi mode?

Tags: jquery, html, geolocation

got a jquerymobile app, the google map loads great on Apple devices in both Wifi and 3G, but with my Android device, it only works on Wifi, if I use 3G, the user never gets prompted to share location..

I've tried using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() & google.loader.clientlocation.

Does anyone know if there's any certain kind of methodology I need to employ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses WPS for coarse location services. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system

For this to work wifi needs to be enabled.

Comment: Hey Tim, thankyou this is very interesting. So there is no way to get Android user location without Wifi? Seems completely bizzard! I need to show a Google map to them, wanted to center map on their approximate location

Comment: as far as I know some versions of android might use the gps signal for browser geolocation...

Comment: And how do we catch that? I've tried using those things above, but they don't seem to catch it, Its just a standard html page

Comment: before getting too deep into it. can you make sure gps is active and has a location? check google maps that this is the case. then visit that page and check.

Comment: try this page perhaps and see what happens? http://maxheapsize.com/static/html5geolocationdemo.html

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your help. Yep I've checked the Client Android device has 'location services' enabled etc, if I jump it on to the wifi it works, then taking it off it fails.

Comment: I don't have the client's Andorid on me now though :(

Comment: Hey Tim, I'm so sorry, but I've just gone and seen the client and found out there was ANOTHER area where you can specify your GPS options. I thought it was only manageable in the browser settings area, but I went to his Android OS settings and found he had both enable wirefi location from Google and the GPS location thing disabled. My apologies! Thanks :)

Comment: no worries! good to know, I remember early versions of android not passing the gps location to the browser. Cheers